# RuntimeWarnings when using factors in GLM

Tags: python, statsmodels, glm

So I am trying to do a logit model with the `glm` function from the `statsmodels` package. My response variable is, yeah, binary, but I also have at least one binary independent variable. However, if I run the function:

```
full_model = sm.GLM(y_var, x_vars, family=sm.families.Binomial())
```

I get a lot of `RuntimeWarning` like divide by zero etc., which makes sense when there are a lot of zeros from the binary variables, and it doesn't use them correctly.

I have tried making them into dummy variables as well (both predictor and response), and given them different types. But I get this RuntimeWarning all the time, and the model output is pretty much useless.

It seems easy to do in R. Am I missing something in order to do it in Python ?

EDIT:

Sample data set:

```
0  71.854894  0      136.100006  55.000000     102.699997   7960.503626  7854.028146  7737.106918  7595.023565  7428.387039  1472.9  24.763004  22.534969  20.631284  18.85136  17.457321  15.520547  13.891387  12.233356  10.555192  8.790123   6.763984  4.607102  0.711363  7442.761158  7195.556908  6977.023668  6777.391449  6592.152960  6418.675354  6255.194055  6100.422739  5953.371137  5813.247705  5679.402249  5551.289539  5428.444875  5310.466963  5197.005474  5087.751755  4982.431722  4880.800317  4782.637117  4687.742801  4595.936264  4507.052257  4420.939405  4337.458560  4256.481399  4177.889232  4101.571983  4027.427307  3955.359824  3885.280457  3817.105847  3750.757836  3686.163018  3623.252333  3561.960711  3502.226753  3443.992441  3387.202882  3331.806077  3277.752710  3224.995957  3173.491315  3123.196442  3074.071018  3026.076610  2979.176552  2933.335836  2888.521012  2844.700089  8051.890149  7981.638185  7936.575350  7892.762733  7838.433780  1981.0      31.718171      29.754665      28.013222      26.35466       25.023021      23.062876      21.231111      19.163032      17.01686       14.726892      12.022372      9.310275       1.721343       7568.386177   7369.515308   7192.308043   7028.905753   6875.960511   6731.599473   6594.587551   6464.024622   6339.212588  6219.587813   6104.682670   5994.101598   5887.505120   5784.598573   5685.123820   5588.852953   5495.583395   5405.134005   5317.341943  5232.060108   5149.155022   5068.505072   4989.999036   4913.534831   4839.018460   4766.363101   4695.488330   4626.319451   4558.786912  4492.825797   4428.375384   4365.378752   4303.782442   4243.536149   4184.592458   4126.906599   4070.436237   4015.141278   3960.983699  3907.927392   3855.938027   3804.982920   3755.030927   3706.052331   3658.018754   3610.903067   3564.679310   3519.322625   3474.809183  1    
1  64.016427  0      56.700001   30.000000     44.200001    7718.060323  7569.869004  7378.936202  7218.383987  7029.767932  1372.0  23.668700  21.527400  19.622000  17.80980  16.509900  14.423000  12.795400  11.136300  9.400300   7.323360   5.069140  2.371360  0.152129  7240.267261  6975.551113  6747.030573  6541.940178  6354.011208  6179.602084  6016.344876  5862.575653  5717.058459  5578.836682  5447.146285  5321.361819  5200.961074  5085.500946  4974.600378  4867.927944  4765.192590  4666.136578  4570.530006  4478.166486  4388.859690  4302.440545  4218.754942  4137.661833  4059.031644  3982.744942  3908.691298  3836.768319  3766.880816  3698.940084  3632.863271  3568.572839  3505.996076  3445.064674  3385.714359  3327.884548  3271.518062  3216.560853  3162.961767  3110.672330  3059.646550  3009.840748  2961.213392  2913.724954  2867.337776  2822.015955  2777.725221  2734.432847  2692.107548  7814.763327  7711.519268  7638.616216  7528.455120  7443.697472  1582.0      25.839000      23.908400      22.202500      20.58880       19.392000      17.506300      15.994600      14.469200      12.84550       10.952300      8.446470       4.345920       0.286673       7330.461737   7101.679657   6903.731904   6724.763448   6559.264268   6404.204170   6257.704351   6118.493547   5985.653488  5858.486960   5736.443742   5619.076261   5506.011586   5396.932925   5291.566933   5189.674696   5091.045148   4995.490137   4902.840648  4812.943851   4725.660750   4640.864297   4558.437838   4478.273839   4400.272811   4324.342408   4250.396663   4178.355325   4108.143296  4039.690132   3972.929623   3907.799407   3844.240642   3782.197714   3721.617974   3662.451504   3604.650914   3548.171150   3492.969332  3439.004595   3386.237958   3334.632197   3284.151733   3234.762523   3186.431975   3139.128853   3092.823200   3047.486267   3003.090443  0    
2  52.082136  0      66.000000   31.299999     58.799999    7864.714237  7810.087141  7757.977675  7715.276756  7637.901408  1580.1  25.910900  24.044500  22.395600  20.82330  19.643000  17.820500  16.352500  14.839000  13.185800  11.345700  9.249000  6.220300  0.034828  7370.859234  7167.828110  6982.879843  6810.848050  6649.092603  6495.960281  6350.295534  6211.234013  6078.098943  5950.342701  5827.511038  5709.219778  5595.138900  5484.981245  5378.494257  5275.453778  5175.659299  5078.930237  4985.102990  4894.028558  4805.570610  4719.603886  4636.012865  4554.690653  4475.538034  4398.462661  4323.378365  4250.204553  4178.865684  4109.290817  4041.413201  3975.169928  3910.501614  3847.352117  3785.668289  3725.399751  3666.498688  3608.919665  3552.619465  3497.556935  3443.692850  3390.989786  3339.412009  3288.925364  3239.497187  3191.096205  3143.692465  3097.257250  3051.763013  7907.794451  7865.835586  7836.004432  7813.166391  7786.353388  2017.7      31.683700      29.714000      27.921900      26.25230       25.065800      23.244100      21.863900      20.433100      18.86250       17.053500      14.860600      11.274700      0.075046       7469.083502   7303.984989   7152.251060   7009.746928   6874.493378   6745.306283   6621.384579   6502.143043   6387.131141  6275.988587   6168.418838   6064.172216   5963.034622   5864.819677   5769.363083   5676.518453   5586.154177   5498.151004   5412.400153  5328.801813   5247.263944   5167.701287   5090.034564   5014.189797   4940.097751   4867.693450   4796.915771   4727.707088   4660.012968  4593.781902   4528.965073   4465.516143   4403.391072   4342.547950   4282.946848   4224.549688   4167.320116   4111.223393   4056.226298  4002.297031   3949.405131   3897.521397   3846.617818   3796.667503   3747.644624   3699.524357   3652.282825   3605.897056   3560.344933  0    
3  65.147159  0      136.600006  55.500000     39.099998    7985.965144  7944.275162  7884.037736  7797.781457  7675.671449  1383.1  22.286700  20.622800  19.144200  17.80080  16.727300  15.244900  13.974700  12.685900  11.342500  9.890590   8.270390  6.134150  0.673057  7467.241438  7252.805471  7055.259808  6870.563045  6696.395519  6531.220735  6373.929869  6223.675715  6079.784200  5941.702670  5808.967502  5681.182678  5558.004994  5439.133460  5324.301480  5213.270935  5105.827612  5001.777595  4900.944390  4803.166583  4708.295923  4616.195725  4526.739535  4439.810000  4355.297908  4273.101358  4193.125044  4115.279641  4039.481255  3965.650953  3893.714336  3823.601170  3755.245053  3688.583116  3623.555760  3560.106415  3498.181325  3437.729349  3378.701786  3321.052214  3264.736341  3209.711867  3155.938368  3103.377176  3051.991274  3001.745206  2952.604979  2904.537990  2857.512942  8011.294804  7989.655465  7974.889673  7956.573166  7935.748574  1645.4      24.935800      23.520200      22.286800      21.20730       20.317800      19.021100      17.913500      16.743100      15.50860       14.280200      12.826000      11.072500      1.499900       7580.649118   7407.941373   7245.475907   7090.853064   6942.813072   6800.551724   6663.492489   6531.190373   6403.284617  6279.472693   6159.494735   6043.123548   5930.157839   5820.417389   5713.739502   5609.976284   5508.992516   5410.663956   5314.875952  5221.522294   5130.504260   5041.729805   4955.112871   4870.572790   4788.033774   4707.424469   4628.677558   4551.729421   4476.519831  4402.991678   4331.090736   4260.765440   4191.966697   4124.647710   4058.763821   3994.272365   3931.132545   3869.305311   3808.753251  3749.440492   3691.332611   3634.396550   3578.600539   3523.914024   3470.307601   3417.752957   3366.222812   3315.690864   3266.131744  0    
4  63.175907  0      72.800003   36.000000     56.299999    7890.047393  7806.023232  7671.423077  7499.701342  7257.235602  1192.0  19.277600  17.450100  15.900300  14.56090  13.610800  12.191600  11.032400  9.849190   8.676960   7.442330   5.856280  3.998220  0.152712  7350.160736  7111.883655  6894.582428  6692.769654  6503.452852  6324.704539  6155.157359  5993.778849  5839.754835  5692.422567  5551.229380  5415.705591  5285.445908  5160.096195  5039.343751  4922.909993  4810.544837  4702.022285  4597.136926  4495.701104  4397.542607  4302.502762  4210.434844  4121.202731  4034.679773  3950.747817  3869.296370  3790.221877  3713.427086  3638.820493  3566.315861  3495.831780  3427.291290  3360.621535  3295.753459  3232.621527  3171.163479  3111.320104  3053.035035  2996.254562  2940.927466  2887.004858  2834.440039  2783.188372  2733.207154  2684.455512  2636.894292  2590.485972  2545.194567  7943.542217  7891.443595  7850.289589  7799.315341  7724.800000  1386.7      21.798200      20.097300      18.623600      17.31660       16.390600      14.989700      13.869500      12.704000      11.51790       10.243800      8.662160       6.621830       0.314905       7442.295567   7236.387241   7046.128337   6867.417485   6698.123005   6536.899802   6382.798397   6235.099537   6093.231932  5956.726352   5825.187735   5698.277081   5575.699087   5457.193357   5342.527942   5231.494467   5123.904377   5019.585975   4918.382068  4820.148050   4724.750334   4632.065050   4541.976955   4454.378507   4369.169081   4286.254296   4205.545426   4126.958898   4050.415841  3975.841703   3903.165897   3832.321500   3763.244974   3695.875923   3630.156874   3566.033070   3503.452297   3442.364715   3382.722708  3324.480749   3267.595273   3212.024561   3157.728633   3104.669153   3052.809331   3002.113848   2952.548770   2904.081477   2856.680598  0
```

Comment: division by zero can also be because of a singular matrix, which can be caused by perfect collinear. Check and make sure that you have drop a dummy for each of the categorical variables that you have to avoid the dummy trap

Comment: But if I remove the one binary independent variable from the predictors, it runs smooth, and the result looks very decent. So shouldn't that at least indicate that the other predictors are not perfectly collinear ?

Comment: Which means the binary independent variable is the one that causes the colinear relationship

Comment: I think we can speculate better and answer better if you post some data, or at least the list of variables that you use.

Comment: I have quite many predictors (they need to be reduced, but I still need this first model that includes everything), and a decent amount of observations. How do you propose I proceed with posting some of the data ? I haven't posted that amount of data before in here.

Comment: You may post the list of variables and perhaps 1 or 2 rows of data. Just copy and paste as plain text should be fine. How many predictors in the full model do you have? Any smaller model that also has the same problem?

Comment: I have now updated with a few samples. As of now I have around 140 independent variables. And needless to say, they need to be reduced. But the way I am trying to do it involves getting the full model developed. But no, if I randomly reduce down to like 30-40 IVs, the model is good without errors, and WITH the binary IV as well. And yes, some of the IV's are highly collinear, I know that in advance (that's why I want to reduce the number of IV's as well).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204637/discussion-between-9mat-and-denver-dang).